# File isn't imported unless I remove a seemingly irrelevant require

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given file `server.js` with these contents:

```
'use strict';
const values      = require('../valueData/values');
const insertValue = require('../valueData/insertValue');
insertValue.insertRecord(null, null, null, null, null);
```

file `values.js`

```
'use strict';
const entity = require('../masterData/entity.js');
console.log('inside values.js');
```

file `insertValue.js`

```
'use strict';
const cache = require('../components/cache.js');
function insertRecord(id, value, valueTimestamp, geolocation, callback) {
    cache.getCached(id, function (error, entity) {

    });
}
module.exports = {
    insertRecord,
}
```

file `cache.js`

```
'use strict';
const entity = require('../masterData/entity.js'); 
const customer = require('../masterData/customer.js');
console.log('CUSTOMER');
console.log(customer);
console.log('ENTITY');
console.log(entity);
function getCached(id, callback) {
};
module.exports = {
  getCached,
}
```

When I execute this, the output will be this:

```
CUSTOMER
{ 
  getCustomerInfoFromDB: [Function: getCustomerInfoFromDB],
}
ENTITY
{ 
}
```

essentially: the `entity` object will contain no functions (yes, they're exported through `modules.export`.

However when I comment the import in `values.js`, I get the expected output:

```
CUSTOMER
{ 
  getCustomerInfoFromDB: [Function: getCustomerInfoFromDB],
}
ENTITY
{ 
  getEntityByID: [Function: getEntityByID],
}
```

What could cause this behaviour? `entity.js` and `customer.js` both have the same imports. Note the the problem is also "fixed" when I comment the `values` import in `server.js` but that is hardly a solution. It all seems to point to the fact that the import in `values.js` messes things up somehow.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the two declarations of `const entity` conflict, and that's your problem.

Comment: @EdCottrell how do they conflict? As far as I understood NodeJS, the `const` would restrict their scope to just that file as everything is implicitly wrapped in a function on file-level.

Comment: Well, I'm not a node expert; I'm a bit of a newbie in it, so I could be missing something. That's why I'm not posting an answer. But my understanding is that the `const`s are global and only the module exports are scope-restricted. Could you try renaming one of the `const`s as a test?

Comment: @EdCottrell: sorry no, doesn't make a difference.

Comment: `const` is block-scoped so that's irrelevant. `var` would have had this behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't put entity.js here (we're talking in a chat room about this where you have linked it), but you linked it in a chat room (I'm not going to post it here unless I'm allowed to) but it showed that you had a circular reference in your requires.

In NodeJS, circular references don't cause errors. Instead, you get something a bit more subtle. Basically, whenever you `require` a package, it is only required once and the code is only executed once. This means that when you have code like this...

```
// alice.js
var bob = require('./bob.js')
bob.say()
module.exports = {
  say: function () { console.log('hello bob') }
}

// bob.js
var alice = require('./alice.js')
alice.say()
module.exports = {
  say: function () { console.log('hello alice!')
}
```

This series of events is going to happen:

1. Alice will be `require`d by the core interpreter.
2. Alice will require Bob.
3. Bob will then require Alice.
4. Alice is already cached, but she exited before setting up her `module.exports`. This means that her `module.exports` will default to being an `{}`.
5. Bob attempts to invoke Alice's `module.exports.say`, which is `undefined`, and gets an error, halting execution.

This appears to be what is happening in your code: When you require the `entity.js`, this requires `cache.js`, which then requires `entity.js` again and tries to use one of its functions immediately. This function is `undefined` because of the behaviour I listed above, and so the code errors.

However, in `insertValues`, you *don't* require `entity.js` but instead `cache.js`. When `cache.js` executes, it requires `entity.js`, but entity.js does not use any of `cache.js`' functions immediately, so there's no error. `entity.js` sets up `module.exports` successfully and cache calls them no problem.

TLDR: circular references are evil! Just because Node doesn't tell you off for using them doesn't mean you should. Move the cyclic behaviour to a tertiary file. It will cause you future headaches if you try and work around this behaviour.